# mysql inserting a row at index 0 for auto increment column

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table where a column called `nameid` is autoincremented. I already have a lot of rows in that table, yet, sometimes, at insertion MySQL assigns the value `0` at this column if there is no other row with that `nameid` value. Worst, if a row gets that `0` value at `nameid` then at successive updates I get the error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry '0' for key 'nameId' An error has occurred:null

Any ideas why this is happening and how to avoid this problem?
Thanks

Comment: What does your Table structure look like? Add it to the post.

Comment: I used ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN nameId INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;

Comment: Why can't that be a `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: there is already one... and I can't change that

Comment: It should be okay for the auto-increment column to be a unique column. It doesn't strictly have to be the primary key.

Comment: What's weird is that `0` doesn't trigger the auto-increment to generate a new value. It is supposed to.

Comment: Found the error: There was a script that was defaulting the value of nameid to 0 if that variable was empty or anything different to an int at the respective json. This was making that nameid 0 to be set. Thx